# É possível testar somente classes específicas?

Tags: java, maven, junit

Eu tenho duas classes de testes:

```
class A {
   @Test
   public void fazAlgo(){
      // ...
   }
}
```

```
class B {
   @Test
   public void fazAlgoMesmo(){
      // ...
   }
}
```

Meus testes estão demorando muito porque estão sendo testadas todas as classes. Há atualizações que não precisam passar por todos os testes, por exemplo, modifiquei a classe `B` e tenho certeza que ela não afetará as demais, mas ainda assim preciso testar o comportamento dela.

É possível testar somente a classe `B`?
Eu sei que se tirar `@Test` do método o teste não será executado, mas ter que colocar/tirar a cada teste é cansativo e consome muito tempo.

Comment: Consegue postar as configurações relevantes do seu `pom.xml`? Existo maneiras de fazer isso com alguns plugins como surefire (tudo vai depender daquilo que está sendo executado quando você chama `mvn test`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## TL;DR

**Sim**, é possível executar testes seletivamente com jUnit, mas a forma como se faz isso depende de como se inicia tal execução.

## Diferentes formas de executar testes

A forma mais simples de executar testes unitários durante o desenvolvimento é através da sua **IDE**. Eclipse, IntelliJ e Netbeans permitem clicar numa classe ou método específica e vai ter alguma opção como *Run as Test* ou *Test as Java Application* e assim por diante.

Com **Maven**, o responsável por executar os testes na fase `test` é o [Maven Surefire plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/). É possível:

- [Pular completamente os testes](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html) passando o parâmetro `-DskipTests`
- [Executar uma única classe ou método de testes](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html) com o parâmetro `-test=<pattern>`, onde o *pattern* aqui é uma expressão regular que pode incluir o nome da classe e, opcionalmente, do método de teste
- [Configurar o projeto para executar testes específicos](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html), lembrando que você poderia criar diferentes perfis ([*profiles*](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)) para executar diferentes baterias de testes, por exemplo, tendo um perfil para *testes rápidos* e outro para *testes completos*

Alguns servidores de integração contínua também podem executar testes automaticamente, mas neste caso a configuração deve ser feita na ferramenta e não no projeto em si.

## Considerações

Testes unitários não devem ser lentos. Se este é o caso, primeiramente considere a possibilidade de reescrever os mais lentos. Remova dependências desnecessários usando Stubs, Mocks ou Fakes.

Por outro lado, em geral um teste lento geralmente significa que ele não é realmente um teste unitário, mas de integração. Um caso comum são testes que fazem chamadas remotas a sistemas de terceiros, ou que inicializam toda a aplicação num servidor embebido.

Nesse caso, tais testes devem ser colocados separadamente dos demais, seja usando configuração do projeto ou até criando um projeto à parte.

No caso do Maven ou Gradle, uma estratégia interessante é ter um projeto composto por vários módulos (subprojetos) dentro os quais um ou mais seriam projetos compostos somente por testes de integração. Eles ainda fazem parte da mesma base de código, portanto são facilmente mantidos em sincronia com o projeto, mas ao mesmo tempo vivem apartados do código-fonte principal e dos testes unitários.

Comment: Eu apanhei um pouco mas consegui resolver, obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 3):

Boa noite renan

Se estiver utilizando maven, existe duas formas de fazer isso.

A primeira é utilizando Single Test atravez da linha de comando, você escolhe qualquer classe que quer testar.

```
mvn -Dtest=ClasseTestB test
```

A segunda forma é configurando no pom.xml para excluir um pacote ou classe em especifico da rodada de test

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/CircleIT.java</exclude>
        <exclude>**/SquareIT.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Você pode conseguir o mesmo resultado tanto com o Maven Surefire Plugin, quanto com o Maven Failsafe Plugin.

Ref1: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

Ref2: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Douglas :)

Answer (score 3):

Pode-se também anotar o método ou a classe de teste que deve ser ignorada com [`@Ignore`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html):

```
// Ignorando todos os testes na classe 'A':
@Ignore
class A {

   @Test
   public void testaAlgo(){
      // ...
   }
}
```

Opcionalmente, pode especificar o motivo de estar ignorando determinado teste:

```
@Ignore("Motivo de estar ignorando o teste")
class A {   

   @Test
   public void testaAlgo(){
      //...
   }
}
```

> No [JUnit5](http://junit.org/junit5), essa anotação será chamada de [`@Disabled`](http://junit.org/junit5#disabling-tests).